# Sparkle Update -- How sparkle notifies download_finish and unarchive_finish

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, sparkle

I want to show a different UI in my client when download and unarchive finishes at background, Is there a sparkle delegate_method or any other way to get notified on unarchive/download finish?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the [Sparkle-code](https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/)  `- (void)updater:(SUUpdater *)updater willInstallUpdateOnQuit:(SUAppcastItem *)item immediateInstallationInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation` delegate method gets called on unarchive_finish.